# Android: How can I share SQLite table with another phone with the same APP

Tags: android, sqlite

I am thinking regarding the future options of my app and I am thinking of the idea of backing-up the data from the application's Database and also sharing that data with another phone, say via e-mail, messaging, Bluetooth, you name it, but basically saving it as a file and opening it from the other phone and having the same values on both phones.

What would be the best approach for such an Android application?

Would Content Providers accomplish exactly this or are they concerned with sharing data only between different Apps? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is possible ,

If you read the documentation about the internal storage [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal), It mentions

> You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them

So i believe you can copy the whole sqlite DB file to some temp location then share that file via BT or email or any other sharing option .

But DO NOTE, that the same application package can only access the file if you want perhaps another application to use the db then u need to set the SharedUserId , as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#sharedUserId)

Content Providers are generally only for sharing your app's data to other apps.

> Content providers are the standard interface that connects data in one process with code running in another process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I believe it is a good answer. I chose to only export a specific part of my DB to a .json file